# Compare specific parts of two columns in a text file in Linux

Tags: linux, text, multiple-columns

I have a text file with several columns separated by tab character as below:

```
    1    ATGCCCAGA  AS:i:10   XS:i:10  
    2    ATGCTTGA   AS:i:10   XS:i:5  
    3    ATGGGGGA   AS:i:10   XS:i:1  
    4    ATCCCCGA   AS:i:20   XS:i:20
```

I now want to compare the last two columns AS:i:(n1) and XS:i:(n2) to obtain only lines with n1 different to n2. So, my desired output would be:

```
    2    ATGCTTGA   AS:i:10   XS:i:5  
    3    ATGGGGGA   AS:i:10   XS:i:1
```

Could you suggest me some ways that I can compare n1 and n2 and print out the output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your desired output appears to be lines where those two values are *different*, not identical...

Comment: Either way, though, it's a trivial line of awk. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As Shawn says, you coudl do this in awk... or perl ... or sed.

An AWK example might be

```
awk '{split($3,a,":");split($4,b,":");if(a[3]!=b[3]) print $0}' infile.txt
```

If you are familiar with awk this should be fairly self explanatory

Comment: If I had remembered sooner to check back to see if OP had clarified the question, I would have suggested  `awk -v FS="[\t:]" '$5 != $8' infile.txt`